# Definite sum for $(1+a)^n$

Tags: functions, exponentiation, binomial-theorem

I hope to find the sum of a series defined by $(1+a)^n$. So far, using binomial expansion the function expands quite nicely into:
$$(1+a)^n=\binom{n}{0}a^0+\binom{n}{n}a^n+\binom{n}{1}a+...+\binom{n}{n-1}a^{n-1}$$
$$(1+a)^n=1+a^n+\frac{n!}{1!(n-1)!}\cdot(a+a^{n-1})+\frac{n!}{2!(n-2)!}\cdot(a^2+a^{n-2})+...+k$$
where $k$ is some *general* term which largely depends on whether *n* is odd or even. I can't quite write it down yet.

I was wondering if you could find the sum for the series, like as you would with:
$$\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{(1+a)^i} = \frac{1-(1+a)^{-n}}{a}$$

Not sure if I make any sense.

Comment: You've already written the sum of the series on the right hand side: it's the left hand side, $(1+a)^n$.

Answer (score 1):

$$(1+a)^1=\binom 10a^0+\binom 11a^1=\binom 10(a^0+a^1),\\
(1+a)^2=\binom 20a^0+\binom 21a^1+\binom 22a^2=\binom 20(a^0+a^2)+\binom 21a^1.$$

For an odd exponent, there is no "$k$" term and there are $(n+1)/2$ pairs with equal coefficients; and for an even exponent, the $k$ term is $$\binom n{n/2}a^{n/2}$$ plus $n/2$ pairs.

---

Anyway, in all cases the sum is just expressed by $(1+a)^n$.